# Would two unmoving electric charges repel each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

I am reading that the electromagnetic force is only transmitted when 2 objects with charge move relative to each other.

In that case, would 2 electrons that are not moving repel? Would 2 unmoving protons attract?

How does static electricity work in if motion is required?

Comment: "I am reading that the electromagnetic force is only transmitted when 2 objects with charge move relative to each other."  Not true.
 You must have misread that book.

Comment: Are you familiar with Coulomb's law?

Comment: *I am reading* Where did you read this and what *exactly* does it say ?  As you have described it this source would be wrong, so we're presuming you have misunderstood, but it's possible that the source material is in error and it would be useful to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am reading that the electromagnetic force is only transmitted when 2 objects with charge move relative to each other.

Be careful with the things, named electromagnetic. What we have are electric interactions, magnetic interactions and electromagnetic induction processes. Furthermore we have electromagnetic radiation.

**Electric interactions** are these between charges. Electrons repeal each other due to their electric field. The same for protons, positrons and anti-protons. Any macroscopic electric interaction happens due to the charge separation.

**Magnetic interactions** are these between the magnetic dipoles of subatomic particles. The common magnetic dipole of atoms and molecules may be neutral or having some value, dependent from the position and alignment of the electrons, protons and neutrons of the atoms. Atoms may form domains, where the magnetic dipoles are aligned. Having aligned dipoles materials are permanent magnets.

**Electromagnetic interactions** are those of three involved value **F**, **v** and **B**:

- a moving with **v** charge, influenced by a magnetic field **B**, gets deflected sideways with a force **F** (electric drive)
- moving (with force) a wire with it free electrons across a magnetic field the electrons start to flow with some velocity (electric generator)
- accelerating electrons in a coil a magnetic field is induces.

Since there is no other model, the interactions of electric and magnetic fields in the three cases mentioned above are mediated by virtual photons. At the PSE there are numerous questions and answers about the virtual photons, which are needed for explanation, but can never be considered real.

One note about photons. They are indeed of electromagnetic nature. Emitted from subatomic particles with their electric and magnetic field components, they have both oscillating electric and magnetic field components and this their name *electromagnetic* radiation comes from.

> In that case, would 2 electrons that are not moving repel? Would 2 unmoving protons attract?

Exact in the case of the electrons. And two protons also repeal each other.  The electric field is an intrinsic (existing independent from surrounding circumstances) property. Any two charged particles - moving or not - will attract or repeal each other.

> How does static electricity work in if motion is required?

The charges have their fields around and these fields are working a bit like springs, attracting different or repealing equal charges.

Answer (score 0):

Opposites attract and likes repel. That's how the electromagnetic cookie crumbles even if the charges are moving.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source means that magnetic field is created by charges in motion only and an **external** magnetic field cannot be produced by a stationary charge. But you should also note that irrespective of motion charges posses electric field which is why electrostatic attraction and repulsion takes place. And 2 unmoving charges will attract or repel in accordance with Coulomb's law.